# What is the difference between socket.io client and socket.io server? Alternatives to socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have been breaking my head on understanding what exactly is socket.io and its role in the whole persistent communication between client and server in general. Some fundamental questions that keep coming up in my mind are :

- Are node.js and socket.io server different ways of doing the same thing ? Like lighthttpd and apache ?
- Why should I use socket.io server if I have node.js ?
- Can I use socket.io client with another server side programming language like PHP ?
- Are there alternatives to using socket.io client ?
- Is socket.io client just another javascript library for websocket communication ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

The Socket.IO server accepts connections from Socket.IO clients.  This is not any different than any other server (such as a web server like Apache) accepting a connection from a client (such as a web browser like Internet Explorer).

Node.js is a platform built on top of the V8 JavaScript engine, which comes with a convenient library usually used for web and network applications.  Socket.IO is a web-socket-like communication wrapper and RPC which enables servers and clients to communicate over a variety of transports (every thing from long-polling JSON to real Web Sockets).  Generally, the Socket.IO server code runs in your JavaScript application running on top of Node.js, and the Socket.IO client runs in your JavaScript on a web browser.  (Note that you **can** run the Socket.IO client in your Node.js application to, which I have used in the past as a quick RPC between multiple Node.js applications.)

There are Socket.IO clients available for many languages, and yes I believe there is one for PHP but I haven't used it personally.

If you want to communicate with a Socket.IO server, you must use a Socket.IO client.  It is a protocol all on its own.

Answer (score 2):

> Are node.js and socket.io server different ways of doing the same thing ?

SocketIO is actually a I/O engine that permits realtime communication between client and server, unlike classic HTTP requests.

> Why should I use socket.io server if I have node.js ?

Since both are differents, we can't compare.

> Can I use socket.io client with another server side programming language like PHP ?

No, because socketIO server run in NodeJS environment.
Client first make a HTTP request, then socketIO send a static JS script to client.
This script establish the two-way communication.
But you can use socketIO server with different socketIO client implementation.

> Are there alternatives to using socket.io client ?

Any socketIO client implementation can do the job since they connected to server. 
But beware of asynchronous way of communication, like in Java or PHP.

> Is socket.io client just another javascript library for websocket communication ?

Yes it is, but socketIO aims on reliability and easy to use, and also do best effort : It choose the best transport available for client.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

> Are node.js and socket.io server different ways of doing the same thing ? Like lighthttpd and apache ?

Socket.io is a framework/library for node.js

> Why should I use socket.io server if I have node.js ?

It's a framework designed for two-way communication, use it if you want

> Can I use socket.io client with another server side programming language like PHP ?

Technically yes. But then you would have to reimplement socket.io server in that other language to match it.

> Are there alternatives to using socket.io client ?

Lots of, google for websocket/real time communication in [here put your language]

> Is socket.io client just another javascript library for websocket communication ?

Socket.io client is a JavaScript library compatibile with socket.io server (which is JavaScript library as well, only on the server side, i.e. Node.js)